# To place div's side by side that generated by for loop(jsp)

Tags: java, javascript, jsp

Let see the following example where divs are generated by for loop

```
 <%
   for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
   if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {
  %>
  <div class="table">
  <img src="<%=email%>/<%=listOfFiles[i].getName()%>" width="130" height="130"> 
   </div>
     <!--like this n-divs are generated by for loop-->

  <%
     } else if (listOfFiles[i].isDirectory()) {
        out.println("Directory " + listOfFiles[i].getName());
     }
   }

  %>
```

I want to print the images in the manner of table having 3 columns and rows are increased dynamically as required ,As shown below

img 1   img 2  img 3   
img 4   img 5  img 6   
-   -   -   -   -  - img n

How can i achieve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting `float: left` with `width: 30%` should do the thing. Also set width for parent div.

Check it here http://jsfiddle.net/XDB9n/